# Expresso returning logged out and to the wrong page

Tags: expresso-store, 2.8

When a user purchases a product they are redirected to the Home page of: `return="/shop/order_complete/ORDER_HASH"`

They are also returned to the site logged out.

Checkout code

```
{exp:store:checkout
    payment_method="PayPal_Express"
    return="/shop/order_complete/ORDER_HASH"
    next="/shop/checkout"
}
  {!-- usual stuff, removed for example --}
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

I can't see anything in my htaccess file that could be causing this issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of EE and Store?

Comment: latest version of both.

Comment: I'd imagine it's probably to do with those leading forward slashes in your paths. Take those away and give it another try.

Comment: Hello, Just taken the slashes out, still redirected to the home page but I did see a flash of an ACT= type url.  I'm not great with htaccess, but this should stop ACT= urls being redirect right? RewriteCond ^(.*)$ !^ACT=.*$ [NC] thanks

Comment: I've just tried disabling htaccess altogether and I've still got this issue.  Everything was working locally.  But now it's not on the staging domain.

Comment: Ah, yes, you definitely don't want to stop ACT URLs being processed. They're pretty critical in EE and Store needs them to function. I also wouldn't completely disable your htaccess file as no doubt you'll need some rules such in there. If the difference is between local and remote then it would suggest a platform difference of some kind. Do you want to ping us an email (support@exp-resso.com) so we can further troubleshoot? It could be good to get access to the site along with FTP/SSH access to check on the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that a rogue index.html file with a redirect inside was the issue.

```
<title>Redirect</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=index.php">
```

Everything hitting the root was being redirected so the ACTion ID's weren't able to process (which is pretty critical for Store payments to process). Removing this file resolved the issue.